# Shipping price disappearing magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.5

when changing anything in the xml of the checkout cart index.xml file, the price next to the freight stops appearing in magento 2.3.5. I'm trying to organize the layout of the content but in any case the price of freight simply disappears when changing anything. Has anyone had this problem?
I tried to replace the Magento_checkout folder in: vendor / magento / module-checkout / view / frontend / layout / checkout_cart_index.html, for: app / design / frontent /  /  / Magento_Checkout / layout / checkout_cart_index. html, But even so when trying to edit the checkout_cart_index file, the value that is next to the freight disappears. I do not know what to do :/ . Help me please is urgent.

Comment: Show your customize xml

Comment: Sohel Rana, I tried to be a little more specific about it. If I put the xml code here it will not fit, but it is still totally standard is the checkout_cart_index file. If I try to change anything about it, the shipping price just goes away. : / Have you had this problem? if you can help me i will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

the xml that i want to change

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <update handle="checkout_cart_item_renderers"/>
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="page.messages">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\ValidationMessages" name="checkout.cart.validationmessages"/>
            </referenceContainer>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart" template="Magento_Checkout::cart.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <container name="checkout.cart.items" as="with-items">
                        <container name="checkout.cart.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="cart-container" before="-">
                            <container name="checkout.cart.form.before" as="form_before" label="Shopping Cart Items Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rewards"/>
                            <container name="cart.summary" label="Cart Summary Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="cart-summary" after="-">
                                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.cart.summary.title" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::text.phtml">
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">Summary</argument>
                                        <argument name="tag" xsi:type="string">strong</argument>
                                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">summary title</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </block>
                                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/shipping.phtml" after="checkout.cart.summary.title">
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="types" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="form.input" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                        <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="summary-block-config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-rates-validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!--Step configuration components-->
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                    <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">summary-block-config</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="block-rates" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/shipping-rates</item>
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="block-shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/shipping-estimation</item>
                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                            <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="0" xsi:type="string">block-summary.block-shipping.address-fieldsets</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="address-fieldsets" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">address-fieldsets</item>
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">115</item>
                                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.city</item>
                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">110</item>
                                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.country_id</item>
                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/region</item>
                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">112</item>
                                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                                                                                <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                            <!-- Value of region_id field is filtered by the value of county_id attribute -->
                                                                            <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="target" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id]]></item>
                                                                                <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <!-- The following items override configuration of corresponding address attributes -->
                                                                        <item name="region" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <!-- Make region attribute invisible on frontend. Corresponding input element is created by region_id field -->
                                                                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">111</item>
                                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.postcode</item>
                                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">114</item>
                                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="checkoutProvider" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </block>
                                <container name="checkout.cart.totals.container" as="totals" label="Shopping Cart Totals">
                                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/totals.phtml">
                                        <arguments>
                                            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals</item>
                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">totals</item>
                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- sort order for this totals is configured on admin panel-->
                                                            <!-- Stores->Configuration->SALES->Sales->General->Checkout Totals Sort Order -->
                                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/subtotal</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/subtotal</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals/shipping</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping</item>
                                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/shipping</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total</item>
                                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </argument>
                                        </arguments>
                                    </block>
                                </container>
                                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/coupon.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.methods.bottom" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/methods.phtml">
                                    <container name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" label="Payment Methods After Checkout Button">
                                        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Magento_Checkout::onepage/link.phtml" />
                                        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\QuoteShortcutButtons" name="checkout.cart.shortcut.buttons" />
                                    </container>
                                </block>
                            </container>
                            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Grid" name="checkout.cart.form" as="cart-items" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/form.phtml" after="cart.summary">
                                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="checkout.cart.order.actions"/>
                            </block>
                            <container name="checkout.cart.widget" as="checkout_cart_widget" label="Shopping Cart Items After"/>
                        </container>
                        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" after="-" ifconfig="checkout/cart/crosssell_enabled">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
                                <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Listing\PreparePostData</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="crosssell.product.addto" as="addto">
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                                       name="crosssell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                            </block>
                        </block>
                    </container>
                    <container name="checkout.cart.noitems" as="no-items">
                        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.empty" before="-" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/noItems.phtml">
                            <container name="checkout.cart.empty.widget" as="checkout_cart_empty_widget" label="Empty Shopping Cart Content Before"/>
                        </block>
                    </container>
                </block>
            </referenceContainer>
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Additional\Info" name="additional.product.info" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/additional/info.phtml"/>
        </body>
    </page>
```